# Hide calendar image of date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]I follow this code and I want to hide image icon calendar of this part of the code, `(datePicker.setMonthpicker("#inq_end_dt", inqEndDt);)` How to do that?

```
setCalendar: function() {       
    var inqStrDt = "";
    var inqEndDt = "";
    if(todate.substr(6,8)<=20) {
        inqStrDt = formatter.datetime(webank.date_minus(todate,todate.substr(6,8)), "yyyy-mm");
        inqEndDt = formatter.datetime(webank.date_minus(todate, todate.substr(6,8)), "yyyy-mm");
    } else {
        inqStrDt = formatter.datetime(todate, "yyyy-mm");
        inqEndDt = formatter.datetime(todate, "yyyy-mm");
    }

    datePicker.setMonthpicker("#inq_str_dt", inqStrDt);

    datePicker.setMonthpicker("#inq_end_dt", inqEndDt);     
}
```

Comment: What's the ID of the calendar icon?

Comment: I used dataPicker.setMonthPicker shows icon calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the element with ID `inq_str_dt`:

```
$("#inq_str_dt").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like that. Now it is fine, Thank you~~~

setCalendar: function(){

```
    var inqStrDt = "";
    var inqEndDt = "";
    if(todate.substr(6,8)<=20){
        inqStrDt = formatter.datetime(webank.date_minus(todate,todate.substr(6,8)), "yyyy-mm");
        inqEndDt = formatter.datetime(webank.date_minus(todate, todate.substr(6,8)), "yyyy-mm");
    }else{
        inqStrDt = formatter.datetime(todate, "yyyy-mm");
        inqEndDt = formatter.datetime(todate, "yyyy-mm");
    }



    datePicker.setMonthpicker("#inq_str_dt", inqStrDt);

    //datePicker.setMonthpicker("#inq_end_dt", inqEndDt);
    $("#inq_end_dt").val(inqEndDt);
}
```